# sort elements using bootstrap and ng repeat in angular js

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to sort my data in angularjs using ng repeat in a way where all data start filling the first column and if there are more it goes to the second.(Like form A)

Like this:

```
form A                        form B
0    3     and not like this  0   1
1    4                        2   3
2    5                        4   5


in this order.
help???

this is the code that i tried: note that this displays the products giving them col-xs-6 (like form B)which is not what i want(form A)
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
      <div>
        <div >
         <div class="col-xs-6">
           {{product}}
         </div>
        </div>    
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, and you should show your code of what you tried if you want to get help on your code

Comment: sorry just edited it.. thanks for your feedback, what about now?